# How to make force use a general chipset driver for a vendor-modded USB Wlan adapter?

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking, usb, drivers

I have a Buffalo WLI-UC-GNHP adapter, which use a Ralink RT3070 chipset (https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Buffalo_WLI-UC-GNHP). But this adapter cannot work out-of-box on Windows and Linux, and it don't even accept new driver from Mediatek, instead, it can only use the driver from Buffalo. (A normal RT3070 adapter should work out-of-box on Windows and Linux, and I can update the driver to the latest one from 2016: http://topics.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/)

I think it's because it use a special VID/PID for buffalo(VID=0411, PID=0158) instead of the Ralink ones (VID=148f, PID=3070) (http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids). Thus I'm stuck to use it on Windows only, and use the old vendor driver from 2009, and have to install it separately.

I thought a few ways to solve this:

1. Modify the VID and PID on the adapter. This is the best way, but I don't know how to do this.
2. Modify a general chipset driver's inf, so it will accept the Buffalo's VID/PID. But the latest driver is a EXE packed with Installshield, I run it without install, and found a .CAB file in my temp folder, I think the driver is inside that, but I cannot unpack it. (Update: I got the original driver files with INF inside.)

Or what else can I do?

Comment: Try this: https://scandic.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14352/~/manual-installation-of-a-downloaded-driver-in-windows-vista-or-7

Comment: @LawrenceC That's the standard way to install driver, of course I tried it, but it refuse to recognize the driver as the correct one.

Comment: You should be able to override it.

Comment: @LawrenceC How?

Comment: Why might Buffalo have changed the VID and PID?

Comment: @unforgettableid I think it's up to vendor's preference, there may not have a technical reason.